# Nested List Hashmap processing in java lambda

Tags: java, java-8

I have some situation where I have page List containing collection of Map name page and in page map I have another List calling Groups, which is look like:

```
List<Map<String,Object>> group = new ArrayList<>();
Map<String,Object> groupMap = new HashMap<>();
groupMap.put("G1F1", null); //<-- null value need to remove from groupMap
groupMap.put("G1F2", "F2value");
groupMap.put("G1F3", "F3value");
groupMap.put("G1F4", null);//<-- null value need to remove from groupMap
group.add(groupMap);

Map<String,Object> groupMap2 = new HashMap<>();
groupMap2.put("G2F1", null);//<-- null value need to remove from groupMap2
groupMap2.put("G2F2", "F2value");
groupMap2.put("G2F3", "F3value");
groupMap2.put("G2F4", null);//<-- null value need to remove from groupMap2
group.add(groupMap2);

Map<String,Object> page1 = new HashMap<>();
page1.put("PageID", "PID1001");
page1.put("Groups", group);

Map<String,Object>  page2 = new HashMap<>();//<-- page2 do not have Groups need to remove from pages
page2.put("PageID", "PID1208");
Map<String,Object>  page3 = new HashMap<>();//<-- page3 do not have Groups need to remove from pages
page3.put("PageID", "PID1212");
Map<String,Object>  page4 = new HashMap<>();//<-- page4 do not have Groups need to remove from pages
page4.put("PageID", "PID1214");
Map<String,Object>  page5 = new HashMap<>();
page5.put("PageID", "PID15555");
page5.put("Groups", group);

pages.add(page1);
pages.add(page2);
pages.add(page3);
pages.add(page4);
pages.add(page5);
```

In the above pages object I need to remove those pages that do not have any Groups and in the Groups I need to remove those items that has null value.

I tried with the following code using java8 lamda but the output is unexpected which is like `[true, true, false, false]`.

```
Object object = pages.stream().filter(page -> page.containsKey("Groups"))
     .map(page -> (List) page.get("Groups"))
            .flatMap(x -> x.stream()).map(group -> ((Map<String,Object>)group).entrySet().removeIf(g -> g.getValue() == null)).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

I'm able to remove all the items in the Groups which contains null value by the following code:

```
pages.stream().filter(page -> page.containsKey("Groups"))
     .map(page -> (List) page.get("Groups")).flatMap(x -> x.stream()).forEach(group -> ((Map<String,Object>)group).entrySet().removeIf(entry -> null == entry.getValue()));
```

But not able to filter out the Pages means if the page donot contains any Groups then I need to remove that page user single statement lambda, I can do it using conventional Java iteration process, which is look like :

```
private static void sanitizePages() {
    Iterator<Map<String,Object>> listIt = pages.iterator();
    while(listIt.hasNext()) {
        Map<String,Object> item = listIt.next();

        if(!item.containsKey(("Groups"))){
            listIt.remove();
            continue;
        }
        List<Map<String,Object>> groups = (List<Map<String,Object>>)item.get("Groups");
        Iterator<Map<String,Object>> groupsIt = groups.iterator();

        while(groupsIt.hasNext()) {
            Map<String,Object> map = groupsIt.next();
            Iterator<Entry<String, Object>> groupIt = map.entrySet().iterator();
            while(groupIt.hasNext()) {
                Entry<String,Object> group = groupIt.next();
                if(null == group.getValue()) groupIt.remove();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But I need lambda solution.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, Streams are not the right tool when you want to *modify* collections, but note that there a several useful methods on the Collections itself.

If you want to win a prize for maximizing the lambda usage, you can use:

```
pages.removeIf(item -> {
    List<Map<String,Object>> groups = (List<Map<String,Object>>)item.get("Groups");
    if(groups==null) return true;
    groups.forEach(map -> map.values().removeIf(Objects::isNull));
    return false;
});
```

But note that there are good old methods like `removeAll` which still work and aren’t more complicated than the lambda based use:

```
Set<Object> nulls=Collections.singleton(null);
pages.removeIf(item -> {
    List<Map<String,Object>> groups = (List<Map<String,Object>>)item.get("Groups");
    if(groups==null) return true;
    groups.forEach(map -> map.values().removeAll(nulls));
    return false;
});
```

Of course, the code was simpler if the collections weren’t type with `Object`, requiring an unchecked type cast…

Comment: Actually I'm starting to work on lamda and it seems that it is more compact form then the conventional programming style, can you please give me some explanation why stream is not correct tool for modify collection, is it performance issue or it is better not to use stream for collection modification

Comment: It’s not their intended use. Generally, having side effects in functions passed to Stream operations is discouraged. If the side effects violate the [Non-interference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#NonInterference) constraint, the code must be considered broken (and may cause exceptions or, even worse, silent data corruption at runtime; depending on the circumstances, it may even appear to work sometimes). Streams are good for *processing* the elements of a collection and you may collect the result into a new collection, but not to modify them.

Comment: This doesn’t imply that you can’t simplify Collection operations using lambda expressions. You can use the new methods offered by the Collection API, like shown in my answer. These are not to be confused with the Stream API. See `Iterable.forEach` and `Collection.removeIf` (both used in my answer) or `List.replaceAll`, `Map.forEach`, `Map.merge`, etc.